# Записать данные в ELF файл

Tags: c, ассемблер

Задача такая, есть к примеру `ELF` файл (который мы сами создали), нужно записать в него (к примеру в конец) некоторые байты и потом вызвать их в самом бинарном файле.

Все это дело надо сделать без помощи линкера и прочих утилит.
Я подумал, что можно создать свою секцию и ее потом как-нибудь модифицировать, пока на этой мысли и остановился.
Подскажите как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Можно просто с помощью `cat` прилепить к исполняемому файлу кусок. Потом сама программа разбирает заголовок ELF, определяет теоретический размер файла, читает данные после предполагаемого конца файла.

Comment: @insolor Или просто ищет начало по какому-то признаку - например, какой-то строке...

Comment: Да, я тоже пришел к такой мысли. Только как определять где начинается склеенный файл? то есть, я могу конечно сделать уникальную метку, но в теории она тоже может существовать в бинарнике.

Comment: @insolor да, можно...я просто пишу легковесную виртуальную машину..гляну библиотеку для парсинга ELF, большая уж слишком.

Comment: Вероятность, что у вас там "в теории" найдется, скажем, строка `"вот они, мои хитро$опые данные"` - по сути, нулевая :) Лично я когда-то, во времена DOS'а, так в одной игрушке делал - дописывал результаты победителей прямо к EXE'шке...

Comment: @JoneGreen, зачем библиотеку, берете спецификацию, одной небольшой функцией реализуете то что вам нужно)

Comment: @Harry, с учётом того, что эта же программа проверяет наличие этой строки внутри себя, то вероятность 100%.

Comment: @insolor Вы серьезно думаете, что я этого не учел? :) Пишем строку типа `char s[] = "_скомая строка";`, делаем `s[0] = 'И'` и ищем. Понятно, что все можно и усложнить - если нужно... По-моему, это очевидно... Куда хуже то, что в Windows писать в открытый exe'шник просто так не выйдет (DOS позволял, в OS/2 был соответсвтующий вызов API... Как в Linux - не в курсе).

Comment: *libelf* из пакета *elfutils* вам в руки.

Answer (score 2):

На месте данных, которые предполагается замещать непосредственно в ELF-е, пишем что-то заметное. Например, так:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    unsigned int a = 0x0F1F2F3F;
    unsigned int b = 0x0E1E2E3E;

    printf("0x%08X, 0x%08X\n", a,b);
}
```

Компилируете, как обычно. 
Запускаете, проверяете, что печатаются именно ваши коды:

```
$ ./a.out 
0x0F1F2F3F, 0x0E1E2E3E
```

После этого, открываете *a.out* с помощью *hexedit*  и ищете в нем эти "приметные" коды". Запоминаете место, где они расположены и исправляете их на что-то другое. Запускаете:

```
$ ./a.out 
0xD0C0B0A, 0xE0D0C0B
```

Проверив, что всё правильно, пишете крохотную программку, которая открывает ваш ELF, 
в режиме "rw",  выполняет *fseek()* и пишет туда нужные значения.